# Conditional expectation for Kelly strategy/criterion

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

> Consider a gambler who at each gamble either wins or loses his bet with
>   probabilities $p$ and $1-p$, independent of earlier gambles. When $p > 1/2$
>   a popular gambling system  known as the Kelly strategy, is to always bet the fraction $2p-1$ of the current fortune. Compute the expected fortune after $n$ gambles, starting with $x$ units and employing the Kelly strategy.

So, I feel I need to use the rule $$\Bbb E[X] =\Bbb E\left[\Bbb E[X\mid Y]\right]$$ where $X =$ Fortune after $n$ gambles and $Y =$ Fortune after $n-1$ gambles.

Also if I start with a fortune $a$, then I will earn $a(2p-1)$ with probability $p$ or lose $a(2p-1)$ with probability $(1-p)$. So my expected current fortune should be $$ap(2p-1) + a(1-p)(2p-1)$$

I don't really know how to continue after this.

Comment: $E(S_{n+1}\mid S_n)=(2-2p)S_n+(2p-1)S_n\cdot 2p=C_pS_n$, hence $E(S_n)=C_p^nS_0$ with $C_p=1+(2p-1)^2=1+\epsilon^2>1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say the gambler currently has fortune $a$, then if he wins, he will earn $a(2p-1)$ and his fortune will become $a + a(2p-1) = 2pa$. If he loses, he will lose $a(2p-1)$ and his fortune will become $a-a(2p-1) = (2-2p)a$.

And we know that all the winning/losing events in the sequence are independent, so the joint probability can be calculated with simple multiplication.

Let's say, out of the $n$ gambles, he wins $i$ times and loses $(n-i)$ times, then after the $i$ wins and $(n-i)$ loss, his fortune will be
$$ a \cdot (2p)^i \cdot (2-2p)^{n-i}$$

Then let's look at the wins and losses of the $n$ gambles. The probability of winning $i$ times (and clearly losing $n-i$ times) is equal to 
$$ \binom{n}{i} p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i} $$
because there are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways of winning exactly $i$ times (and losing exactly $(n-i)$ times).

Thus the expectation after $n$ gambles would be 
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}a(2p)^{i}(2-2p)^{n-i} $$